# How to get the date on date/time record type

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component, datetime

How can i get the date on the date/time record type. So that i can condition this if `Start_Date_Time__c = End_Date_Time__c`. If true the output is like this:

> Friday, 26 June 2015 from 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM (Greenwich Mean Time)

If false the output may like this:

> From Monday, 29 June 2015 , 3:13 PM to Tuesday, 30 June 2015 , 3:13
>   PM (Greenwich Mean Time)

here is my vf code:

```
< apex:outputText value="{!IF(Event__c.Start_Date_Time__c = Event__c.End_Date_Time__c, "{0,date, EEEEE',' d MMMM yyyy ',' h:mm a} to {1,date, h:mm a '('zzzzz')'}", "From {0,date, EEEEE',' d MMMM yyyy ',' h:mm a} to {1,date, EEEEE',' d MMMM yyyy ',' h:mm a '('zzzzz')'}")}"/><br/>
<apex:param value="{!Event__c.Start_Date_Time__c+(8/24)}" /> 
<apex:param value="{!Event__c.End_Date_Time__c+(8/24)}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

The condition still wrong because of the time was included. I just want to condition it with the date only. Is this possible. Hope you get me.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:-

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!DATEVALUE(Event__c.Start_Date_Time__c) == DATEVALUE(Event__c.End_Date_Time__c)}" value="From {0,date, EEEEE',' d MMMM yyyy ',' h:mm a} to {1,date, EEEEE',' d MMMM yyyy ',' h:mm a '('zzzzz')'}">
<apex:param value="{!Event__c.Start_Date_Time__c+(8/24)}" /> 
<apex:param value="{!Event__c.End_Date_Time__c+(8/24)}" /> 
</apex:outputText>

<apex:outputText rendered="{!DATEVALUE(Event__c.Start_Date_Time__c) != DATEVALUE(Event__c.End_Date_Time__c)}" value="{0,date, EEEEE',' d MMMM yyyy ',' h:mm a} to {1,date, h:mm a '('zzzzz')'}">
<apex:param value="{!Event__c.Start_Date_Time__c+(8/24)}" /> 
<apex:param value="{!Event__c.End_Date_Time__c+(8/24)}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

DateValue should give you what you need. I've also split the criteria out into a rnedered attribute to make reading easier.

Comment: Yeah.. just noticed.. the condition (operator) was interchange.. thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a checkbox formula field and use the value on your visualforce page. If dates are the same, the checkbox will be true automatically. Otherwise it will remain it as false.

Remember that sometimes platform offers functionality you can use and you don't need code #clicksnotcode

[image]